# Показывать описание только у выбранного элемента

Tags: vue.js, vuex

когда нажимаю на кнопку, у меня открывается описание ко всем услугам, как можно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии открывалось описание именного того товара, у которого решил посмотреть?

Вот код:

```js
toggleRequest(item) {
  this.$store.commit('setItemInfo', item)
  this.setRequest(!this.isShowRequest)
}

setItemInfo(state, item) {
  state.item_in_cart_info = item
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="col-12 cart-product" v-for="item in cart" :key="item.id" :style="'flex-direction:' + (item.type == 2 ? 'column' : 'row')">
  <div class="prod-about">
    <div class="prod-name-price">
      <span class="prod-name">{{ item.name }}</span>
      <span class="prod-price">{{ getPriceProduct(item) }} ₽</span>
    </div>
    <img v-if="item.request_service" @click="toggleRequest(item)" class="caret-down" src="../../assets/svg/caretDown.svg" />
    <!--@click="toggleServDescr(item)"-->
    <div class="add-product" v-if="item.type == 2">
      <a class="btn cancel" @click="item.count <= 1 ? toggleModalDel(item) : item.count--">Отменить</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="request-product" v-if="item.request_service && isShowRequest">
    <div class="request-block" style="align-self: flex-start;"><span>{{item.request_service}}</span></div>
    <a class="btn change-serv" style="align-self: flex-end;" @click="toggleModalServ(); closeModal()">Изменить</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Понимаю что всё из-за этого v-for, но как можно реализовать не понимаю

Comment: У вас не рабочий пример, но кажется проблема в том, что вы открываете описание в цикле v-for.
Вынесите описание за цикл
<div v-for="" >
ПЕРЕБОР
</div>
<div>
Описание, которое надо открыть
</div>

Comment: Проблему уже решил, сделал реюзабельный компонент, и передал пропсы в него, так как до этого карточка отрисовывалась единожды и содержала в себе все остальные карточки товаров